# What is the unix test -f command equivalent in powershell?

Tags: unix, powershell

I'm converting unix scripts into powershell scripts. 
 I want to know the **unix test -f equivalent command in powershell.**
If anybody is knowing this, please answer me.

Comment: sorry, Its "test -f" while writing i made mistake.

Answer (score 3):

`test -f FILE` exits with a success error code if "FILE exists and is a **regular file**". For PowerShell, you probably want to use `Test-Path -Type Leaf FILE`. We need the `-Type Leaf` to make sure that `TestPath` don't return `$true` for directories.

`test -f` and `Test-Path -Type Leaf` aren't going to be 100% identical. The fine differences between them may or may not matter, so I'd audit the script just to be sure. For example, `test -F some_symlink` is not true, but `Test-Path -Type Leaf some_symlink` is true. (Well, it was when I tested with a NTFS symlink.)

NB: `test` may be a built-in command in whichever shell you are using. I assume it has the semantics I quoted from the [man page for test](http://ss64.com/bash/test.html) that I found.